# Create custom primitive function of a list type using custom variable types

Tags: python, featuretools

I have a question about featuretools's `make_agg_premitives` function.

In my data there are values that consist of list format.

For example,

```
    id       products 
    a         ['a', 'b', 'c']
    b         ['a','c']
    a         ['a','c']
```

I want to aggregate the `products` columns by using various custom functions:

```
def len_lists(values):
   return len(a)

len_ = make_agg_primitive(function = len_lists,
                           input_types = [?????],
                           return_type = ft.variable_types.Numeric,
                           description="length of a list related instance")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use featuretools to create a custom variable type that can be used with a custom primitive to generate the transform feature that you want.

> Note: The operation that you want to do is actually a transform primitive, not an aggregation primitive.

Using your example let’s create a custom List type

```py
from featuretools.variable_types import Variable

class List(Variable):
    type_string = "list"
```

Now let’s use our new List type to create a custom transform primitive, and generate features for a simple entityset that contains a List variable type.

```py
from featuretools.primitives import make_trans_primitive
from featuretools.variable_types import Numeric
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft

def len_list(values):
    return values.str.len()

LengthList = make_trans_primitive(function = len_list,
                                  input_types = [List],
                                  return_type = Numeric,
                                  description="length of a list related instance")

# Create a simple entityset containing list data
data = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3],
                     "products": [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a','c'], ['b'] ]})

es = ft.EntitySet(id="data")
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="customers",
                              dataframe=data,
                              index="id",
                              variable_types={
                                   'products': List # Use the custom List type
                              })

feature_matrix, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                  target_entity="customers",
                                  agg_primitives=[],
                                  trans_primitives=[LengthList],
                                  max_depth=2)
```

You can now view the features generated, which include features that used the custom transform primitive

```py
feature_matrix.head()
```

```
    LEN_LIST(products)
id
1                    3
2                    2
3                    1
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you! thanks to you, I'm gonna to make various functions!

in the code 
def len_list(values):
    return values.str.len()

a format of values is dataframe, right?